# How to implement dependent input fields Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm building a invoice system where item name and price retrieved from database . Price is dependent on item name .

Now i have to do this .

```
Price: <Input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
Qty : <Input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" />
Tax : <Input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" />
Discount : <Input type="text" id="disc" name="disc" />
Total : <Input type="text" id="total" name="total"  value=" echo $total;"/>
```

I want to autofill total input field without reloading with this following formula

```
<?Php 
$total = $price * $qty + $tax - $disc;
?>
```

Comment: could you create a short snippet to help understand the flow? coz if you are going to take user inputs for  QTY, TAX , DISCOUNT you could use an onchange event and use javascript to calculate the total with the formula.

Comment: might be helpfull, http://jsfiddle.net/5gsBV/7/

Comment: why not use Javascript for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

need to assign class in your html, and some jquery script,

```
//Assign Amount class in your 4 html fields

    Price: <Input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="amount" />
    Qty : <Input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="amount"/>
    Tax : <Input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" class="amount"/>
    Discount : <Input type="text" id="disc" name="disc" class="amount"/>
    Total : <Input type="text" id="total" name="total"  value=" echo $total;"/>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('input.amount').keyup(function(){   
        var price = $("#price").val();
        var qty = $("#qty").val();
        var tax = $("#tax").val();
        var disc = $("#disc").val();
        var total = $("#total").val();
        total = ((parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty) + parseFloat(tax) - parseFloat(disc);
        $("#total").val(parseFloat(total));
       });
    });
```

Comment: its working but a small problem is there.  tax is not adding (+). instead of addition tax field attached in the last as a string. example: price = 10, Qty = 2, tax = 12, discount = 0,  total =2012. but its total should be 32, thanks for your efforts

Comment: can quantity be float? decimal value?

Comment: update last two line in my js  with these,  total = ((parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty) + parseFloat(tax) - parseFloat(disc);
 $("#total").val(parseFloat(total);

Comment: let me create fiddle for you

Comment: Thanks its working after some small changes . thank you very much for your efforts. you a nice guy. thanks again .

Answer (score 2):

It should be as,

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input.amount').keyup(function(){   
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    var tax = $("#tax").val();
    var disc = $("#disc").val();
    var total = $("#total").val();
      var total = (parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty)) + (parseFloat(tax) - parseFloat(disc));
    $("#total").val(parseFloat(total));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Price: <Input type="text" class="changing" id="price" name="price" />
Qty : <Input type="text" class="changing" id="qty" name="qty" />
Tax : <Input type="text" class="changing" id="tax" name="tax" />
Discount : <Input type="text" class="changing" id="disc" name="disc" />

$('input[class^=changing]').on('change', function() {
var total = $('#price').val() * $('#qty').val() + $('#tax').val() - $('#disc').val();
$('#total').val(total);

});
```

You can use Jquery to watch changes in fields like price,qty,tax and discount and change the total value everytime it changes

Comment: its working but a small problem is there. tax is not adding (+). instead of addition tax field attached in the last as a string. example: price = 10, Qty = 2, tax = 12, discount = 0, total =2012. but its total should be 32, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to do the math, but you need ajax to load the data from your database.

once all your data about specific product loaded, you can use this jquery code below

```
<script>
    $("#qty, #disc").change(function(){
        $("#total").val( $("#price").val() * $("#qty").val() + $("#tax").val() - $("#disc").val() )
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the jQuery plugin called DependsOn at https://dstreet.github.io/dependsOn/

It probably came out around the same time when this question was posted. But it does the job in a clean way. And it's not the only library out there doing this.